# Java singleton enum programmed to the interface?

Tags: java, multithreading, enums, singleton

This is my first post on here so I will try to be precise. This is for a university project, we have to create a fish tank simulation on top of an OO architecture that we individually make. I'm exploring the uses of singletons and have found them quite useful, however reading online the way I currently implement it is not thread safe.

The way I currently implement it (Think its the lazy method) Note: We have to go through the interface

```
public interface myInterface
{
  void foo();
}

public class myClass implements myInterface
{
  private static myInterface instance;

  private myClass(){}

  private static myInterface Instance()
  {
     if(instance == null)
       instance = new myClass();

     return instance;
  }

  public void foo()
  {
    //Do stuff
  }

  public void bar()
  {
   //Do More Stuff
  }
}
```

This works well however its not thread safe I could add the synchronized keyword to the getter but I've read that that is quite heavy on the system and I have quite a few singletons.

```
private synchronized static myInterface Instance()
{
  if(instance == null)
    instance = new myClass();

  return instance;
}
```

I have then moved on to an enum singleton which is thread safe and is not heavy on the system however I am unsure on how to program it to the interface.

```
public enum myClass implements myInterface
{
  INSTANCE;
  private myClass(){}

  public void foo()
  {
    //Do stuff
  }

  public void bar()
  {
   //Do More Stuff
  }
}
```

In programming to the interface I mean when I call the singleton I can only access methods that are in the interface (please correct me if I'm referring to this wrongly). This is where the way I have done the enum singleton fails. For example: With the lazy singleton I can not call this as its not in the interface:

```
 myClass.Instance().bar();
```

But it can call this which is correct, as it is in the interface.

```
myClass.Instance().foo();
```

With the enum however I can call this and its not programming to the interface

```
myClass.INSTANCE.bar();
```

I understand why its doing this as the class is an enum so it will be able to call everything in that enum class. So after this long post which I apologise for, the main question is: Can I make the enum version only call methods that are declared in the interface?

If it can't how heavy is a synchronized method on the system, I would have around 4-6 of them?

Please Note: Even though this is for a university project we are only running the simulation on one thread so it does not even need to be thread safe. I don't quite understand multi-threading but I thought it would be a good learning opportunity.

Comment: Re, "I've read that [synchronized] is quite heavy on the system."  That depends.  Will your program be calling the getter millions of times per second? or a few times per hour?  Don't waste time trying to solve a performance problem before you have evidence that there actually _is_ a performance problem (Google for "premature optimization").  Also, if your threads actually _are_ calling the getter often enough to cause a problem, then why not have each thread cache its own copy of the reference instead of calling the getter each time the reference is needed?

Comment: Re, "I have quite a few singletons."  That sounds like bad design.  Any time a program has "quite a few" of _anything_, you should be thinking about how to represent whatever they are as object in a _container_.

Comment: @jameslarge "I have quite a few singletons" This would be referring to my "managers" and "factory's" that are responsible for the creation and maintaining of Entity's, AI behaviors, etc. Knowing this would you still consider it a bad design as why would you want to allow more than one manager?

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked what "quite a few" meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always hide your enum implementation as well if you prefer the enum route:

```
public interface Singleton {
    void foo();
}

public final class SingletonAccessor {

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonImpl.INSTANCE;
    }

    private SingletonAccessor() {
    }

    private enum SingletonImpl implements Singleton {
        INSTANCE;
        public void foo() {
            // ...
        }
        public void bar() {
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Peter Lawrey in the comments, you can even use an enum for the SingletonAccessor :)

```
public enum SingletonAccessor {

    SINGLETON;

    public Singleton get() {
        return SingletonImpl.INSTANCE;
    }

    private enum SingletonImpl implements Singleton {
        INSTANCE;
        public void foo() {
            // ...
        }
        public void bar() {
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use an `enum` for the SingletonAccessor as well ;) +1

Comment: An `enum` doesn't have to have any instances ;) I call this a "utility" class.

Comment: @WillyduPreez Thanks! This has worked for me I would never of thought about hiding the enum implementation makes total scene but would never of thought about it

Answer (score 1):

You can cast it to the interface or

```
myInterface my = myClass.INSTANCE;
my.foo();
```

You can still use a method like

```
myClass.getInstance().foo();
```

But this isn't a real solution IMHO.

> Can I make the enum version only call methods that are declared in the interface?

Ultimately you have to decide which methods you want on the instance which are `public`.  If you make a method or field public, you can access it and if you don't want to be able to access it, make it private.

At some point you have to trust you know what you are doing and you do things for a reason.  You don't have to think up ways to prevent yourself from call code you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

just simply change your singleton class this way:

```
public class myClass implements myInterface
{
  private static myInterface instance = new myClass();

  private myClass(){}

  private static myInterface Instance()
  {
     return instance;
  }

  public void foo()
  {
    //Do stuff
  }

  public void bar()
  {
   //Do More Stuff
  }
}
```

this will assure that the singleton object will be created at class-loading time, and you don't need to worry about race-conditions in the `Instance()` method

Comment: How is this better than using an `enum`?

Comment: he has no problems with the interface

Comment: Which he can use with an `enum` which is simpler and he don't have to worry about forgetting to make the class `final` for example.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, he can't use it the way he wants! that is what the question is about, right?

Comment: The question is "Can I make the enum version only call methods that are declared in the interface?" so I assumed that is what he/she wanted.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, then read his post one more time, his problem is, that he thinks, that synchronized `Instance()` is heavy on the system, and that is the only reason he tries to use `Enum` for Singleton anyways

Comment: Fair point, while I don't agree, this is an alternative solution. I would make the class `final` though. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference. Specifically compareAndSet.

```
instance.compareAndSet(null, new MyClass());
```

That is if your instance field is null, set to new object, if not null, leave intact. Should be less heavy.

Comment: This creates an object every time it is called. This could be more expensive than using synchronized.